# Show google maps location based on selected HTML dropdown option

Tags: html, google-maps

Is it possible to show a location on google maps immediately after selecting an option from a html dropdown form?

```
<select class="js-select2" name="service">
    <option>test1</option>
    <option>test2</option>
    <option>test3</option>
    <option>test4</option>
</select>
```

For example I assigned location A to "test1" and location B to "test2". How do I make it so that if I select "test1" google maps will immediately show location A on the map and if I click "test2", the same map will immediately show location B?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You just need to include `onchange="myFunction()"` inside your `select` html tag. This way, your original tag

```
<select class="js-select2" name="service">
```

Will be changed to

```
<select class="js-select2" name="service" onchange="myFunction()>
```

Later you implement the javascript code inside `myFunction()` to invoque your Map with the selected location.

More info: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SCR19.html

Comment: Your answer helped a lot. I actually got it fully to work in a much shorter time than I expected. Thanks!

Comment: @J.K.Harthoorn many years of html/js here eh eh... Thank you J.K. !!! God bless you and keep coding man. Glad that it worked. :)

Comment: Do you maybe know how I can achieve it so that I see this screen? https://i.gyazo.com/c7e74ca2ca0b8350daa4616fdabba34e.png. I want that if I show a location, it also shows the side window with all the reviews and photos. Now, I only see a marker without that side window. So I want what you can see on the image. Any idea on how to achieve that? Thanks for the kind comments hehe ^^

Comment: Nooo... sorry... did not investigate this "maps-tab" until now. Probably it's just a matter of passing some needed parameters to the desired url, or maybe the use of some special url. Best luck.

Comment: New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48895426/display-google-maps-side-window-information

Comment: Nice one. And if you do want to follow where runners are, see this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.statos.multiplayergps