# Display google maps side-window information

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

How do I display the google maps side-window information on my website? 
This is what it's displaying on my website right now:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/9030cb7eae84da77ff0e8f70d917e6d3.png]

But this is what I want:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/c7e74ca2ca0b8350daa4616fdabba34e.png]

I am using this code, which just shows the location with a marker:

```
function showGoogleMaps() {
if (document.getElementById("GPMAP").value == "test1"){

}
if (document.getElementById("GPMAP").value == "test2"){
var position = [52.077488, 4.262157];
}
if (document.getElementById("GPMAP").value == "test3"){
var position = [52.073351, -1.014658];
}
if (document.getElementById("GPMAP").value == "test4"){
var position = [22.077488, 4.262157];
}
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position[0], position[1]);

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16, // initialize zoom level - the max value is 21
    streetViewControl: false, // hide the yellow Street View pegman
    scaleControl: true, // allow users to zoom the Google Map
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: latLng
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googlemaps'),
    mapOptions);

// Show the default red marker at the location
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLng,
    map: map,
    draggable: false,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
}
```

So how do I display the side-window with all the reviews and photos etc.?

Comment: Just did this with a mobile app and had to use places api to get that information and display it accordingly. It will supply an object of the specific place with reviews, photo links and the rest of the information. Soley using google maps doesnt have that capability (as far as I'm aware of)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at places api.

Answer (score 0):

Update from 2023 - try the Google Maps Extended Component Library which includes the UI component you're interested in: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/extended-component-library